# How to make linked readline library relocatable in Cmake

Tags: c, dll, cmake

Firstly, I am not sure if the title exactly words my question well but after three days of searching the web and SO for no working answer, please bear with me.

So the problem is that I have a C application where CMake is the build system. This application relies on `libreadline` and I can correctly find and link with it using the snippet below:

```
find_library(READLINE_LIBRARY readline REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myExe PRIVATE "${READLINE_LIBRARY}")
```

The problem is that when I build the application on a system with say for example `libreadline.so.8` which is the version 8 and move the application to another system that only has `libreadline.so.7` or none available, I'll have to install the missing library before I can run the application. This make for a very bad user experience.

I have tried setting the `@rpath` before the `add_executable` and `add_library` with:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH}:$ORIGIN")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

The problem is that while that correctly sets the `@rpath` for a shared library which forms part of the project, it doesn't do the same for `libreadline`. Also even if for any reason I am able to get it to work, I don't know how to get call to `find_library` return a relocatable library (meaning I can't bet that the `libreadline.so.8` was build with `-fPIC` or not).

Whatever I do, I can't get a local copy of `libreadline` in my build output directory.

Also note that this problem exists on OSX as well just using the Linux example for simplicity.

On OSX when I inspected the executable with `tool -l myExe`, I noticed that only the `Load Command` section for the shared executable which is part of my project correctly uses `@rpath` while the editline (OSX deadline seems to just be an editline) looks like this:

```
Load command 14
      cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
  cmdsize 56
     name /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib (offset 24)
```

Any help will be appreciated. I'm quite stuck. But one thing I'm certain of it that I have seen applications that does this which means it's very possible.

Comment: Don't use `find_library` _except_ to set the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property of `IMPORTED` targets.

Comment: Have you considered linking statically to libreadline 8?

Comment: So what would you recommend instead?

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to force CMake to statically link to the readline library.

Comment: Have you considered packing everything into a container (e.g. `docker`)?

Comment: @CraigEstey Not appropriate for my use case.

Comment: If you _just_ do: `-lreadline`, look at `readelf -a myprogram`. It should _not_ add full paths. It should just reference: `libreadline.so` (which is probably a symlink). The symlink would get resolved [correctly] on the target. If it references `libreadline.so.5`, then that lib has to installed on the target. Alternately, ship an installer (e.g. bash/python/perl script) that just has `.o` files and does the final link on the target. It may have to probe the target a bit to find the best link method.

Comment: If you link against system `libreadline.so.8` and want to launch your app on a system where it may not be present, you should distribute `libreadline.so.8` and all it's dependencies with your application. You also may want to use `patchelf --set-rpath \$ORIGIN libreadline.so.8`, because the library was not built by you. Alternatively, you can use package managers (vcpkg or conan) to build the library from source and either link statically or copy + patch automatically.